# Spring: Programmatically load properties file to an object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, multi-tenant

In a multi-tenant Spring Boot application, I'm trying to load configuration objects. Ideally, I'd like to load certain properties file into a configuration object programmatically. I'm looking for a simple way to load the configuration by passing a properties file and the final class to map it to. The following is just an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

**Directory structure of the configurations:**

```
 config/
     - common.properties
     all_tenants_config/
         - foo_tenant/
            - database.properties
            - api.properties
         - bar_tenant/
            - database.properties
            - api.properties
```

**Configuration POJOs:**

```
class DatabaseProperties {
   @Value("${database.url}")
   private String url;
}

class APIProperties {
   @Value("${api.endPoint}")
   private String endPoint;
}
```

**Configuration Provider:**

```
 @Singleton
 class ConfigurationProvider {

   private Map<String, DatabaseProperties> DB_PROPERTIES = new HashMap<>();
   private Map<String, APIProperties> API_PROPERTIES = new HashMap<>();
   
   public ConfigurationProvider(@Value(${"tenantsConfigPath"}) String tenantsConfigPath) {
        for (File tenant : Path.of(tenantsConfigPath).toFile().listFiles()) {
            String tenantName = tenant.getName();
            for (File configFile : tenant.listFiles()) {
                String configName = configFile.getName();
                if ("database.properties".equals(configName)) {

                    // This is what I'm looking for. An easy way to load the configuration by passing a properties file and the final class to map it to.

                    DB_PROPERTIES.put(tenant, SPRING_CONFIG_LOADER.load(configFile, DatabaseProperties.class));

                } else if ("api.properties".equals(configName)) {
                    API_PROPERTIES.put(tenant, SPRING_CONFIG_LOADER.load(configFile, API.class));
                }
            }
        }
   }
   
   public currentTenantDBProperties() {
       return DB_PROPERTIES.get(CURRENT_TENANT_ID);
   }

   public currentTenantAPIProperties() {
       return API_PROPERTIES.get(CURRENT_TENANT_ID);
   }

}
```

In short, is there a way in Spring that allows to map a properties file to an object without using the default Spring's configuration annotations.

Comment: Try loading files using `@Resource` following this [example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotations-resource-inject-autowire)

Comment: @artiomi I don't understand how `@Resource` can be used to solve this. Can you please provide an example? The aim is to map these properties files to an object.

Comment: Maybe I didn't got the point, but I thought that you can use it as `@Resource @Qualification(${"tenantsConfigPath"}) String tenantsConfigFile` instead of `@Value(${"tenantsConfigPath"}) String tenantsConfigPath`

Comment: @artiomi I don't think you understood the question. I'm looking to map a properties file to an object. Something like this: `DatabaseProperties object = SPRING_PROPERTIES_LOADER.load("database.properties", DatabaseProperties.class));`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this case you do not need any Spring's feature.
Spring is a bean container, but in this place you just new an object by yourself and put it on your map cache.
Step 1: decode property file to Java Properties Class Object
Step 2: turn your properties object to your target object, just use some utils like objectmapper

```
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("db.properties"); // replace file name with your variable
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(reader);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    DatabaseProperties databaseProperties = mapper.convertValue(p, 
    DatabaseProperties.class);
```

Comment: I was thinking about moving properties to json files and use `ObjectMapper` to map them to POJOs. But I didn't know `ObjectMapper` also transforms properties files. So that's good. I'll try out.

Comment: did ObjectMapper work?

Answer (score 0):

The `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation can do the job, allowing you to load external properties. For example from the applications.properties file.

#### Example: simple POJO [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.java-bean-binding)

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.propperties")
public class MyProperties {
  // syntax key properties: `[prefix].[fieldName]=value`
  private String version, name;

  // syntax key properties: `[prefix].[fieldName].[key]=value`
  private Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  public Map<String, String> getMap() { return map; }

  public String getVersion() { return version; }
  public void setVersion(String version) { this.version = version; }

  public String getName() { return name;  }
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

The preceding POJO defines the following properties:

- `my.propperties.version` string type
- `my.propperties.name` string type
- `my.propperties.map.[key]` Map type

`my.propperties` is the prefix defined in the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation. By default, properties are loaded from the `applications.properties` file, but we can import external property files with with "`spring.config.import`" into your applications.properties. `"spring.config.import=filepath".` [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.importing)

In applications.properties file:

```
my.propperties.version=1.0.0
my.propperties.name=awesome name
my.propperties.map.key0=A
my.propperties.map.key1=B
my.propperties.map.key2=C

# or import one file
spring.config.import=fileBar.properties

# or import multiple file
spring.config.import=fileFoo.properties,\
                     fileBar.properties
```

---

##### Create pojo  (used as a type in hashmaps)

```java
class DatabaseProperties {
  private String url;
  public String getUrl() { return url; }
  public void setUrl(String url) { this.url = url; } 
} 
class APIProperties {
  private String endpoint;
  public String getEndpoint() { return endpoint; }
  public void setEndpoint(String endPoint) {this.endpoint = endPoint; } 
}
```

---

##### Create the class with the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation and `@Configuration` annotation.

- `@Configuration` annotation to indicate its role as a Spring configuration class.
- `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation to enable binding of properties from the applications.properties file.

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.cfg") // => "[prefix].api.[object]=[value]"
class MyConfig {
  public static String CURRENT_TENANT_ID = "foo_tenant";

  // => [prefix].api.[key | tenant_id].[field name]=value
  private final Map<String, APIProperties> api = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  // => [prefix].database.[key | tenant_id].[field name]=value
  private final Map<String, DatabaseProperties> database = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  private String tenant, dev;

  public String getDev() { return dev; }
  public void setDev(String dev) {this.dev = dev; }

  public String getTenant() {
    // use tenant id from common.properties
    // return tenant;
    // or use from static field
    return MyConfig.CURRENT_TENANT_ID;
  }
  public void setTenant(String tenantId) { this.tenant = tenantId; }

  public Map<String, APIProperties> getApi() {return api;}
  public Map<String, DatabaseProperties> getDatabase() {return database; }

  public DatabaseProperties currentTenantDBProperties() {return this.getDatabase().get(this.getTenant());}
  public APIProperties currentTenantAPIProperties() {return this.getApi().get(this.getTenant());} 
}
```

The preceding POJO defines the following properties:

- `my.cfg.dev` string type
- `my.cfg.tenant` string type
- `my.cfg.api.[key].[fieldName]` Map<DatabaseProperties> type
- `my.cfg.database.[key].[fieldName]` Map<APIProperties> type

---

##### Create the different properties files:

file: `src/main/resources/config/common.properties`

```
my.cfg.tenant=bar_tenant
my.cfg.dev=true
```

file: `src/main/resources/config/all_tenants_config/bar_tenant/api.properties`

```
my.cfg.api.[bar_tenant].endpoint=https://localhost/api/v1
```

file: `src/main/resources/config/all_tenants_config/bar_tenant/database.properties`

```
my.cfg.database.[bar_tenant].url="localhost"
```

file: `src/main/resources/config/all_tenants_config/foo_tenant/api.properties`

```
my.cfg.api.[foo_tenant].endpoint=https://api.url.com/api/v1
```

file: `src/main/resources/config/all_tenants_config/foo_tenant/database.properties`

```
my.cfg.database.[foo_tenant].url="https://database.url.com"
```

note: You need to surround your key by [] to preserve its original value OR any characters that are not alpha-numeric, - or . are removed. binding map. see: [doc binding map](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.maps)

---

Use your configuration in your service, component, controller, etc.

```
public class IndexController { 
  public IndexController(MyConfig cfg) { 
    cfg.currentTenantAPIProperties(); // use the configuration
  } 
}
```

More information: [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config)

[Gist with the complete code of my test for this example here](https://gist.github.com/tmslpm/63c2d43542c769be85b8996054cf51fb)